# Looking for latest results by using group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by

i'm trying to create an overview page for my customers and would like to show when the customer (within the last year) used a type of service (e.g. window cleaning or floor cleaning).

I tried it this way:

```
SELECT start, project_id, category_id, MAX(start) 
FROM `time_entries` 
WHERE project_id = '$project_id' AND start > '$oneyearago' 
GROUP BY category_id
```

project_id = kind of a unique customer id

category_id = 1 for window cleaning, 2 for floor cleaning and so on

start = DATETIME when the last service started

I would like to show the LAST services, but it only shows the oldest services. What am i Doing wrong? does anyone here has a idea for me?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: This is the database example

```
id   project_id category_id      start

---|------------|-----------|-------------------

1  |  1         | 1         |  2019-11-11 09:51:07

2  |  1         | 2         |  2019-11-12 09:51:07

5  |  1         | 3         |  2019-11-13 09:51:07

3  |  1         | 1         |  2020-11-11 09:51:07

4  |  1         | 2         |  2020-11-12 09:51:07

5  |  1         | 3         |  2020-11-13 09:51:07

6  |  1         | 1         |  2021-11-11 09:51:07

7  |  1         | 2         |  2021-11-12 09:51:07
```

I would like to see

category 1: last appointment was 2021-11-11

category 2: last appointment was 2021-11-12

category 3: last appointment was 2020-11-13

Comment: please share create table and sample data insert script. Also, output expected from sample data. Try with GROUP BY  start, project_id, category_id

Comment: I tried to insert a demo database, i hope this can clear up things :)

Comment: I can not reproduce. Please look: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=fb8ac3e06a84c05b9cf92dc8bd822d94&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: You are very right, it was my mistake. I echoed "start", but not the Max(start), this was very stupid.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was a very stupid mistake. I'm very sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I was asking for scripts like this

```
CREATE TABLE time_entries (id int, project_id int,  category_id int, start datetime);

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES(1 , 1 , 1 , '2019-11-11 09:51:07'),(2 , 1 , 2 , '2019-11-12 09:51:07'), (5 , 1 , 3 , '2019-11-13 09:51:07'), (3 , 1 , 1 , '2020-11-11 09:51:07'), (4 , 1 , 2 , '2020-11-12 09:51:07'), (5 , 1 , 3 , '2020-11-13 09:51:07'), (6 , 1 , 1 , '2021-11-11 09:51:07'), (7 , 1 , 2 , '2021-11-12 09:51:07');
```

Now, solution to your problem. you can add date check in where clause.

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.start, T1.project_id, T1.category_id, T2.start
FROM time_entries T1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT  category_id, MAX(start)start
    FROM time_entries 
    WHERE project_id=1
    GROUP BY  category_id
)T2 ON T1.category_id=T2.category_id AND T1.start = T2.Start
ORDER BY T1.category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query

```
SELECT project_id, category_id, MAX(start) as last_datetime FROM time_entries WHERE project_id = '$project_id' GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: if we add ID field in select statement then this will not work.